# MySQL and Perl Driver Issue - DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found

Tags: mysql, perl, driver

I've just started learning perl. So i am getting introduced to database connectivity here. For this i am using XAMPP server installed on my windows7 machine. Following is a sample piece of code that i have written for testing database.

```
#!D:\xampp\perl\perl.exe
print " Enter Name : ";
chomp($name=<STDIN>);
print " Enter Age : ";
chomp($age=<STDIN>);

use DBI;

$dbh=DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:test');

$insert="insert into student values ('$name',$age)";
$d=$dbh->prepare($insert);
$d->execute();

$s="select * from student";
$s1=$dbh->prepare($s);
$s1->execute();

while(@v=$s1->fetchrow_array)
{
    print "$v[0] \t $v[1] \n";
}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

As you might be able to see that i'm using the test database available in the phpmyadmin database. i have created a student table with name and age as columns. But when i run this code in my browser i get the following error.

> C:\Users\dellpc\Google Drive\coding\web>perl datab.pl
>   Enter Name : one
>   Enter Age : 20 
>   install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load
>   'D:/xampp/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll' for module
>   DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at
>   D:/xampp/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 190,  line 2.  at (eval 4)
>   line 3. Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 3,  line
>   2. Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected  at datab.pl line 9.

I browsed over Google to find out what this error could mean. It seemed that i was missing a file called libmysql.dll , which i downloaded and copied in the xampp perl/bin and the perl/vendor/.../DBD directory as well but this did not help.

I also tried using older version of XAMPP , the issue still persists. Does anyone has any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance. :)

**Edit 1:**

This is the error i get when i try install commands.

```
> cpan> install DBI
```

> T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.634.tar.gz   Has already been unwrapped into directory
>   D:\xampp\cpan\build\DBI-1.634-HZNMVR Could not make: Unknown error
>   Running make test   Can't test without successful make Running make
>   install   Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

cpan> install DBD::mysql Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'

> Running make for C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.033.tar.gz   Has already
>   been unwrapped into directory
>   D:\xampp\cpan\build\DBD-mysql-4.033-3pgMhg
>   'D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL' returned status 512, won't
>   make Running make test   Make had some problems, won't test Running
>   make install   Make had some problems, won't installRunning install for module 'DBI' Running make for

Comment: Does the file 'D:/xampp/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll' exist? Have you installed DBD::mysql? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: This file was already there. http://prntscr.com/adhey3
Also i tried using the install command
cpan> install DBI
cpan> install DBD::mysql
It also did not help.

Comment: Is that the right way to install i.e. using cpan for xampp or should i use something else?

Comment: Using "cpan" (or "cpanm") seems fine. But it seems that something isn't quite right here. I'm afraid I avoid Windows, so I can't be any more help.

Comment: I appreciate the help , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround this:

It seems the xampp version of perl is somewhat not ready or has missing files. So i just installed strawberry Perl, and the program ran without any issue. I hope it helps any others who are looking for a fix.